# React Native: Proper way to handle huge forms

Tags: react-native

I have an application developed for internal users. The home page of the app has at least 30 input fields.

```
<TextInput onChangeText={onChangeNumber} value={number}/>
```

I have onchangeText for all the 30 inputs, in the future I might add more fields. I don't think adding onchange to all the fields is the best way to do it. How can I optimize the approach? Are there any 3rd party packages where it doesn't re-render for every input change and only captures data on submit?

Answer (score 1):

the way I handle large forms is this,
Store your form data in an object using useState like this,

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({name: "", age:""})
```

you can pass "onChangeText" like this,

```
<TextInput
   value={formData.name}
   onChangeText={value => setFormData(prev => { return { ...prev, name: value } })}
/>
```

I would suggest creating a separate component for "TextInput", so you can also handle validations in it.

Comment: Still, we need to use onChangeText on every field right?

Comment: yes, but with this it can be done in one useState only

Answer (score 0):

Try using onEndEditing, as per docs:

> onEndEditing
> Callback that is called when text input ends.

So just changing to
`<TextInput onEndEditing={onChangeNumber} value={number}/>` should do

There are a few other alternatives on the docs, you might check to see the one that fits you better.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onendediting

Comment: yes, tried that approach. But there is one issue with that. "Note that on iOS this method isn't called when using keyboardType="phone-pad". This is from the docs.

Comment: Did you try on endEditing?

Answer (score 0):

You should try **formik** + **yup**.

I am using it in several projects and this is the best way to manage little and big forms!

Comment: Thanks! will try. Do you think this will have any performance issues?

Comment: it is better in terms of performance than one useState for each input